# Set required attribute on Html.Textbox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm looking to create a Bootstrap styled textbox, specifically, based on the exact example below:

```
<input class="span3" type="email" required>
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
@Html.TextBox("CustomerEmail", null, new { @class = "input-xlarge", type = "email", required = "required" })
```

However, `required = "required"` clearly doesn't return just `required`.

So, my question is, is there any way I can force it to return required like in the first example above when using Html.Textbox?

Comment: Why would you want to produce invalid HTML? The correct syntax is clearly `required="required"`.

Comment: I am aware of this, though as it did not yield the same functionality as http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms, I thought that it may be prudent to try to use it the same way to see if that resolved it.

Comment: This is not invalid HTML as per the HTML5 specification. The correct syntax is only _required_. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-required-attribute

Answer (score 82, accepted):

i think you should use like this

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "text", type = "email", required = "required" })
```

i think this will help you.

Comment: How did this answer the question? Does this not render `required="required"` ? Personally, Im working on accessibility problems and even though `required="required"` is valid syntax, for screen readers I'm under the impression it is best to have `required` by itself.

Answer (score 20):

Try

```
new { required = string.Empty}
```

As an aside, according to the W3C docs, `required` is a [Boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute), and I quote:

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>   If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

Therefore

```
required
required="required"
required=""
```

all mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have applied a different class to the textbox: `input-xlarge`, whereas in your desired markup it's called `span3`.

So:

```
@Html.TextBox(
    "CustomerEmail", 
    null, 
    new { 
        @class = "span3", 
        type = "email", 
        required = "required" 
    }
)
```

As far as the required part is concerned, the correct syntax here is `required="required"`, otherwise you simply get broken HTML.

Comment: I know this. The example I provided from my code contains the class I wish to use and is therefore correct and that wasn't my question.

In addition to this, required can be set in a number of ways though i am looking to replicate the way it has been set in the Bootstrap documentation to see if it yields the same result.

Comment: This helper will generate semantically identical code to what you have shown as desired output. So I guess what you have shown as *desired markup* is not that much desired as it doesn't work quite well. Anyway this has strictly nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. I guess you have some problem with the styles, ...

Comment: No, I have referred merely to the "required" portion of the example I provided as the attribute is the desired output.

Comment: `required` and `required="required"` are strictly identical, except that the first is incorrect and broken HTML but client browsers understand it. Anyway you simply cannot force an HTML helper such as TextBox to generate broken HTML. It's not how HTML helpers were designed. If you want to generated broken HTML you will have to do it by hand or write a custom HTML helper. I am afraid that ASP.NET MVC cannot help you here.

Comment: Again, the first is not incorrect nor broken, it is the latter that is incorrect. The presence alone of boolean attribute in the HTML5 specification means true, while the absence of the attribute means false. http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-required-attribute

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you can also use.

```
required="true"
```

The interesting thing is that you get a warning message in Visual Studio 2015 regardless. I wonder if this is a problem with a need for updating.

Warning Message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Message     Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'required' is not a valid attribute of element 'TextBox'.
```