# How to use HTML5 required with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

My application is MVC.

In HTML5 we can use `required`

Such as

```
<input type="text" name="username" required>
```

How do I tell MVC to use the required attribute as my code

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Name, new { @class = "textBox", placeholder = "Required", required })
```

does not do it!

Comment: use attribute in model

Comment: `[Attribute(RequiredAttribute)]` does not help. It complies but doesn't show me the message `it is a required field` when I enter an empty value

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-validation

Comment: This isn't an answer. This works on a post back based upon the model... If I used 'required' then it appears to work client slide. Hate it or love it, try W3School for example http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276817/set-required-attribute-on-html-textbox

Comment: @Alex,  thank you.  It is a dupe, i did look and research, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess your Placeholder is also not working,

Try replacing

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Name, new { @class = "textBox", placeholder = "Required", required })
```

WITH

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Name, new { @class = "textBox", @placeholder = "Required", @required  = "required"})
```