# textboxfor don't read class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html.textboxfor

My original code is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-border-bottom" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre" required >
```

and I want to transform in asp.net calling it from a model... but it don't call classes:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control, input-border-bottom", @id = "name", @name = "name", @placeholder = "Nombre" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove comma between classes

```
 @class = "form-control input-border-bottom"
```

See [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CVeubn)

Comment: @GerardoVentas Just remove the comma, see `"form-control input-border-bottom"` you can check the sample

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276817/set-required-attribute-on-html-textbox)

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the comma

```
@class = "form-control, input-border-bottom"
```

To

```
@class = "form-control input-border-bottom"
```